# Forced Factory Reset on Android TV (reboot loop)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, android-tv

My Android Sony Bravia has the boot-loop problem. It turns on, gets to the Sony logo, reboots, infinitely. Sometimes it gets to the android logo but never further than that.

So I am following the instructions from Sony, after about 20 trials and after reading that you are supposed to press the volume down button lightly I finally managed to see the green light. However after that it restarts and the loops simply continues. What am I doing wrong? Is this an indication, that there is a hardware problem? Can I deduce from this, that the motherboard is working, but that there is perhaps a faulty power cable? Or could this be a software problem?

I also tried to flash the firmware via USB, which didn't work.

Comment: Does the TV has an external or internal power converter? If it is external you may be right with the "faulty cable theory".

Comment: Its internal I think. Just a cable comes out the tv, which I plug in directly into the power outlet, no box.